# How to start the jquery nivo slider when all images are loaded?

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I am using the slider for very big images and on slow clients it happens, that the slider is already at slide 3 before the first picture is loaded and shown.

Is there any way to start the slider only after all the images have loaded ??

Answer (score 1):

Put your slider code in `onload` event:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // your slider code
});
```

The `onload` event files when all page elements; DOM, images, external resources have loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your js code with document ready:
[here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)